# Outer Measure question of confusion.

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I want to construct the following example to use as a counterexample with respect to something involving outer measure.

Let $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$.  Let $\rho$ be defined as follows:

\begin{align}
\rho(E) = \begin{cases}
0 & E = \emptyset \\
1 & E = X \\
\frac{3}{4} & E \subset X.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Therefore, it is the case that, $\mu^{*},$ the outer measure induced by $\rho$, defined as:

\begin{align}
\mu^{*}(A) = \inf\left\{\sum_{1}^{\infty} \mu(E_{j}): \; E_{j} \in \mathcal{E}, \; A \subset \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_{j} \right\}
\end{align}

is given by
\begin{align}
\mu^{*}(E) = \begin{cases}
0 & E = \emptyset \\
1 & E = X \\
\frac{3}{4} & E \subset X.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

So, it seems that all three axioms of the outer measure are satisfied and $\mu^{*}$ is an outer measure.

However, this would also imply by Caratheodory's theorem that for two disjoint subsets of the interval,

\begin{align}
A &= [1.5,2] \\
E &= [1.5,1.7] \\
F &= [1, 1.2].
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
.75 = \mu^{*}(E \cup F) < 1.5 = .75 + .75 = \mu^{*}(E) + \mu^{*}(F)
\end{align}

However, $E \cap F = \emptyset$ and thus, by countability of measures, since $E, \; F \in \mathcal{M}$ where $(\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is the measure space on the sigma algebra generated by the set of outer measurable sets (via Caratheodory), we should have that $\mu = \mu^{*}|_{\mathcal{M}}$ but clearly don't have
\begin{align}
\mu^{*}(E \cup F) = \mu^{*}(E) + \mu^{*}(F).
\end{align}

Comment: It is unclear to me why your definition for the outer measure is given by...how do you justify that the infimum is equal to the values $0,1,3/4$?